# Github Action exit code 66: Directory "...." does not contain an Xcode project, workspace or package

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, github-actions, xcode14

i have a Github Action with the purpose of creating a build for my iOS app. This is the part of my .yml file that is having the issue:
**xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/runner/work/glik-android-react/glik-android-react does not contain an Xcode project, workspace or package.**

```
- name: build archive
        run: |  
          xcodebuild -scheme "Glik" \
          -archivePath $RUNNER_TEMP/glik.xcarchive \
          -sdk iphoneos \
          -configuration Debug \
          -destination generic/platform=iOS \
          clean archive
```

How can i manipulate that path in order that the action correctly finds the Xcode workspace, and successfully creating the build?

I think (not 100% sure) that the correct path should be:
**/glik-android-react/ios**

because there i have the Glik.xcworkspace file that i have always used to build the app locally.

Thanks in advance!

I tried adding something like this:

`archive_path="$RUNNER_TEMP/ios/glik.xcarchive"`

But the path did not change at the moment of the build, so i had the same issue.